# Android calling fragments

Tags: android

I am calling a fragment class from my activity class through intent but it is throwing exception

> boolean java.lang.String on a null object reference

Here is my code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

         if (result.equals("JobCancelled")) {

            fragment = new MyOrdersFragment();
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .replace(R.id.frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

         }

            pdilog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
```

Comment: post full code of this file

Comment: With whatever code you have posted, I guess `result` is passed as `null`. Verify it once.

Comment: Your result is null, nothing to do with fragments.

Comment: no ,the result is not null

Comment: Post the full stack trace. You only posted part of the error which is hard to determine the issue with your code.

Comment: @MonishKamble Doesn't matter if the fragment tag is hardcoded or if you use `.getClass().getSimpleName()`. Both works fine.

Comment: post the exeption please and in which line does it give you that exception.

Comment: @SrikarReddy : Just to correct you. That was not my comment. I guess you have mistakenly tagged me.

Comment: @MonishKamble Apologies. May be tagged the wrong person.

Comment: post your asynTask code.